# Geometric meaning of killing spinors

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

I know about killing vectors- They forms the basis for the isometries of a metric space.

I am not clear about the definition of killing spinors, in the sense related to the one which is there for killing vectors, which i understand. If someone could explain it to me or suggest some reference which illustrates it in some detail, That would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @JonMark Perry - I have made changes in the question, Please tell me if it is clear now.